# Unparseable date exception - Month Date Format

Tags: java, date, parsing

I have this format(String) of date: 4 AM CST  9 DEC 16

I want to parse it using this code:

```
String sDate = "4 AM CST  9 DEC 16";
Date st = new SimpleDateFormat("h aaa z d MMM yy",Locale.ENGLISH).parse(sDate);
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                            DateFormat.LONG, 
                            DateFormat.FULL, 
                            new Locale("no"));
                    sDate = formatter.format(st);
```

But i'm having this exception instead:

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "4 AM CST  9 DEC 16"

I'm really not sure but was it because the month in my sDate, the characters are all in uppercase value and the dateformat "MMM" the only uppercase letter is the first letter of each month?

Comment: can't reproduce (jdk 1.8.0_77) your code works fine

Comment: jdk 1.6.0_45 and 1.7.0_80 works fine too

Comment: Are you on Android? Maybe something with the text resources is different from the input on your platform... You might try to find out via printing `DateFormatSymbols.xyz(...)` what is behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm using jdk 1.7.0_80. When i also tried running it on a separate class, it's working fine but when i implemented it on our system it still shows the same problem.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String sDate = "4 AM CST  9 DEC 16";
    Date st = new SimpleDateFormat("h aaa z d MMM yy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(sDate);
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
        DateFormat.LONG,
        DateFormat.FULL,
        new Locale("no"));
    sDate = formatter.format(st);
    System.out.print(sDate);
  }
}
```

works fine.
I have java version "1.8.0_77"

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason of this exception may be of your regional setup in the computer. Unless you don't define Locale, in the DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance() method, it will take Locale info from your computer default regional location and format.

I have experienced such exception while modifying existing project when my colleague didn't get such exception in the same project and exactly same development environment. Then I crossed checked with his regional setting in control panel. The project was in **Japanese Locale and date format**  but by computer date format was English (UK). After changing the format code didn't give error further.

Go to control panel -> Clock, Language and Region -> Region

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good to know. When the questioner has explicitly specified `Locale.ENGLISH` in the code, that is hardly the problem in this case, though.